# ASCII text in bash without using banner

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get a string from user, for example adem.
Then print this out like ascii text. Character should change, too (not only dots it may * - whatever user enters.)

```
   .
.     .
.......
.     .
.     .
```

Here is my bash script. I thought it could be useful if I divide them each row. Then concatenating each letters' own rows for each row.

```
echo Enter text:
read text
echo Enter character style:
read k

row1=([a]="    $k    " [b]="$k$k$k$k$k" [c]="$k$k$k$k$k")
row2=([a]="$k      $k" [b]="$k      $k" [c]="$k        ")
row3=([a]="$k      $k" [b]="$k$k$k$k$k" [c]="$k        ")
row4=([a]="$k$k$k$k$k" [b]="$k      $k" [c]="$k        ")
row5=([a]="$k      $k" [b]="$k$k$k$k$k" [c]="$k$k$k$k$k")

strlen=${#text}

# Testing echo.
echo " $k    $k     $k  "

echo $satir1[a]

for((i=0; i<=strlen; i++))
do
  echostrline1+=${row1[${text:i:1}]}
  echostrline2+=${row2[${text:i:1}]}
  echostrline3+=${row3[${text:i:1}]}
  echostrline4+=${row4[${text:i:1}]}
  echostrline5+=${row5[${text:i:1}]}
done

echo $echostrline1
echo $echostrline2
echo $echostrline3
echo $echostrline4
echo $echostrline5
```

I have three problems, here.

1. First I can not access row1[a] it doesn't work >> echo $satir1[a]
   (prints last element)
2. When I run the script It's not printing the way I expected.
3. If I enter * as a character it prints directory contents.

I tried to change for loop like that.

```
for((i=0; i<strlen; i++))
do
  echostrline1+=" ${satir1[${metin:i:1}]}"
  echostrline2+=" ${satir2[${metin:i:1}]}"
  echostrline3+=" ${satir3[${metin:i:1}]}"
  echostrline4+=" ${satir4[${metin:i:1}]}"
  echostrline5+=" ${satir5[${metin:i:1}]}"
done
```

Comment: Where do you set `$satir1`?

Comment: Always quote your variables. Otherwise wildcards are expanded, and that's why `*` prints your directory.

Comment: by itself this: `row1=([a]="    $k    ")` generates this: `typeset -p row1` => `declare -a row1=([0]="")`; since your intention appears to be to populate an associative array you need to first declare the array as associative ... `declare -A row1; row1=([a]="    $k    ")` so that you end up with: `typeset -p row1` ==> `declare -A row1=([a]="    .    " )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix the errors there, all your questions should be solved. It is a great tool. Try it!

> 1. First I can not access row1[a] it doesn't work >> echo $satir1[a] (prints last element)

Array access in bash does not work unless you add (the otherwise optional) parentheses around the expansion: `$satir1[a]` --> `${satir1[a]}`.

> 3. If I enter * as a character it prints directory contents.

Because the `echo $echostrline1` at the end is unquoted, special symbols like `*` and `?` are interpreted as glob patterns. Quoting prevents this.

> 2. When I run the script It's not printing the way I expected

That's pretty vague. A question like this should make a concrete example. The main problem is probably with the missing quoting in `echo $echostrline1` too. Because of word-splitting in unquoted variable expansions `x="a    b c"; echo $x` will be printed as `a b c` (repeated spaces are squashed).

Also, like markp-fuso commented, the associative arrays have to be explicitly defined as such using `declare -A row1=(...)`

Btw: `((i=0; i<=strlen; i++))` iterates one time too much. E.g. `text=abc` has three letters, but the loop tries to acces the `0`th, `1`th, `2`nd, and `3`rd letter (which does not exist).

---

Manually defining one array for each line seems a bit complicated and also makes it harder to change the letter size. Hence, I'd propose below solution:

```
#! /bin/bash

IFS= read -p"Enter text: " -r text
IFS= read -p"Enter character style: " -n1 -r k
echo; echo

declare -A index=([A]=0 [b]=1 [c]=2 [u]=3)

while IFS=: read -r -a font; do
  for ((i=0; i<${#text}; i++)); do
    char=${text:i:1}
    glyph="${font[${index[$char]}]}"
    printf %s "${glyph//W/$k}"
  done
  echo
done << 'EOF'
 WW   :W     :     :       :
W  W  :WWW   : WW  :W   W  :
WWWW  :W  W  :W    :W   W  :
W  W  :WWW   : WW  : WWW   :
EOF
```

Example usage

```
Enter text: bAcubA
Enter character style: @

@      @@               @      @@
@@@   @  @   @@  @   @  @@@   @  @
@  @  @@@@  @    @   @  @  @  @@@@
@@@   @  @   @@   @@@   @@@   @  @
```

Implementing the same thing in `awk`, `perl` or any other language would be way easier and more efficient than doing it in plain bash. But I think you already know this, and just see this as an exercise in bash. Otherwise you could have used `banner`, `figlet`, `toilet`, or another tool like that.

Comment: I'm getting an error declare: -A: invalid option. I'm using a Mac, and your solution only prints the last element like mine. Online compiler it works, may be Mac is the problem here. Thanks for solution.

Comment: @ademclk Since you already used associative arrays in your code, I did not assume you were using Mac OS which pre-installs an unbelievably outdated version of bash: 3.2 from the year 2006. Associative arrays were added in bash 4.0 from the year 2009, more than 13 years ago! Unless you plan to ship this script to other Macs, I'd recommend to just upgrade your bash installation.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the code provided by [@Soccowi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6770384/socowi), I mapped the alpha-numeric characters and most symbols into a function as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

printAsBanner() {
        local text="$1" ; shift #Text to print
        local k="$1"    ; shift #Character to use [default: '#']
        [ -z "${k}" ] && k="#"
        declare -A index=([?]=0 [A]=1 [B]=2 [C]=3 [D]=4 [E]=5 [F]=6 [G]=7 [H]=8 [I]=9 [J]=10 [K]=11 [L]=12 [M]=13 [N]=14 [O]=15 [P]=16 [Q]=17 [R]=18 [S]=19 [T]=20 [U]=21 [V]=22 [W]=23 [X]=24 [Y]=25 [Z]=26 [z]=27 [0]=28 [1]=29 [2]=30 [3]=31 [4]=32 [5]=33 [6]=34 [7]=35 [8]=36 [9]=37 [!]=38 [z]=39 [#]=40 [$]=41 [%]=42 [^]=43 [&]=44 [z]=45 [(]=46 [)]=47 [{]=48 [}]=49 [-]=50 [=]=51 [_]=52 [+]=53 [:]=54 [;]=55 [\']=56 [\"]=57 [/]=58 [z]=59 [.]=60 [,]=61 [~]=62 [|]=63)

        ## Convert to uppercase
        text="$(echo "${text}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')"

        while IFS=: read -r -a font; do
          for ((i=0; i<${#text}; i++)); do
            char=${text:i:1}
            if [ " " = "$char" ]; then
                glyph="${font[27]}"
            else
                glyph="${font[${index[$char]}]}"
            fi
            printf "%s" "${glyph//#/$k}"
          done
          echo
        done << 'EOF'
         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :     :         :        :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :        :    :         :       :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :     :         :         :         :         :       :         :         :      :       :       :       :       :       :         :       :     :     :     :         :         :         :     :     :         :# :
 #####   :   #     :######   : #####   :######   :#######  :#######  : #####   :#     #  :###  :      #  :#    #  :#        :#     #  :#     #  :#######  :######   : #####   :######   : #####   :#######  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :####### :    :  ###    :  #    : #####   : #####   :#        :#######  : #####   :#######  : #####   : #####   :###  : #####   :  # #    : #####   :###   #  :  #    :  ##     :         :  ##  : ##    :  ###  :###    :       :       :         :       : #   :     :###  :### ###  :      #  :#        :     :     : ##      :# :
#     #  :  # #    :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#        :#        :#     #  :#     #  : #   :      #  :#   #   :#        :##   ##  :##    #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :   #     :#     #  :#     #  :#  #  #  : #   #   : #   #   :     #  :    : #   #   : ##    :#     #  :#     #  :#    #   :#        :#     #  :#    #   :#     #  :#     #  :###  :#     #  :  # #    :#  #  #  :# #  #   : # #   : #  #    : #   #   : #    :   #   : #     :   #   :       :       :         :  #    :###  :###  :###  :### ###  :     #   : #       :     :     :#  #  #  :# :
      #  : #   #   :#     #  :#        :#     #  :#        :#        :#        :#     #  : #   :      #  :#  #    :#        :# # # #  :# #   #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#        :   #     :#     #  :#     #  :#  #  #  :  # #    :  # #    :    #   :    :#     #  :# #    :      #  :      #  :#    #   :#        :#        :    #    :#     #  :#     #  :###  :# ### #  :#######  :#  #     :### #    :#   #  :  ##     :  # #    :#     :    #  : #     :   #   :       :#####  :         :  #    : #   :###  : #   : #   #   :    #    :  #      :     :     :    ##   :# :
   ###   :#     #  :######   :#        :#     #  :#####    :#####    :#  ####  :#######  : #   :      #  :###     :#        :#  #  #  :#  #  #  :#     #  :######   :#     #  :######   : #####   :   #     :#     #  :#     #  :#  #  #  :   #     :   #     :   #    :    :#     #  :  #    : #####   : #####   :#    #   :######   :######   :   #     : #####   : ######  : #   :# ### #  :  # #    : #####   :   #     :       : ###     :#######  :#     :    #  :##     :   ##  :#####  :       :         :#####  :     :     :#    :         :   #     :   #     :     :     :         :# :
   #     :#######  :#     #  :#        :#     #  :#        :#        :#     #  :#     #  : #   :#     #  :#  #    :#        :#     #  :#   # #  :#     #  :#        :#   # #  :#   #    :      #  :   #     :#     #  : #   #   :#  #  #  :  # #    :   #     :  #     :    :#     #  :  #    :#        :      #  :#######  :      #  :#     #  :  #      :#     #  :      #  :     :# ####   :#######  :   #  #  :  # ###  :       :#   # #  :  # #    :#     :    #  : #     :   #   :       :#####  :         :  #    : #   :###  :     :         :  #      :    #    :###  :###  :         :# :
         :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#     #  :#        :#        :#     #  :#     #  : #   :#     #  :#   #   :#        :#     #  :#    ##  :#     #  :#        :#    #   :#    #   :#     #  :   #     :#     #  :  # #    :#  #  #  : #   #   :   #     : #      :    : #   #   :  #    :#        :#     #  :     #   :#     #  :#     #  :  #      :#     #  :#     #  :###  :#        :  # #    :#  #  #  : #  # #  :       :#    #   : #   #   : #    :   #   : #     :   #   :       :       :         :  #    :###  :###  :     :         : #       :     #   :###  :###  :         :# :
   #     :#     #  :######   : #####   :######   :#######  :#        : #####   :#     #  :###  : #####   :#    #  :#######  :#     #  :#     #  :#######  :#        : #### #  :#     #  : #####   :   #     : #####   :   #     : ## ##   :#     #  :   #     :####### :    :  ###    :#####  :#######  : #####   :     #   : #####   : #####   :  #      : #####   : #####   :###  : #####   :  # #    : #####   :#   ###  :       : ###  #  :         :  ##  : ##    :  ###  :###    :       :       :         :       : #   : #   :     :         :#        :      #  :###  : #   :         :# :
         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :     :         :        :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :        :    :         :       :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :         :     :         :         :         :         :       :         :         :      :       :       :       :       :       :#######  :       :     :#    :     :         :         :         :     :#    :         :# :
EOF
}

printAsBanner "abcDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|/,."
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    #
   #     ######    #####   ######   #######  #######   #####   #     #  ###        #  #    #  #        #     #  #     #  #######  ######    #####   ######    #####   #######  #     #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #######       ###      #     #####    #####   #        #######   #####   #######   #####    #####    ##      ###   #####     # #     #####   ###   #    #      ##      #####     ##   ##                                    ###  ###    #       #
  # #    #     #  #     #  #     #  #        #        #     #  #     #   #         #  #   #   #        ##   ##  ##    #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #     #     #     #     #  #     #  #  #  #   #   #    #   #        #       #   #    ##    #     #  #     #  #    #   #        #     #  #    #   #     #  #     #  #  #  #  ###  #     #    # #    #  #  #  # #  #    # #    #  #    #     #   #       #              #                   #        #   #      #
 #   #   #     #  #        #     #  #        #        #        #     #   #         #  #  #    #        # # # #  # #   #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #           #     #     #  #     #  #  #  #    # #      # #        #       #     #  # #          #        #  #    #   #        #            #    #     #  #     #      ##   ###        #  #######  #  #     ### #    #   #    ##           #  #         #             #           #####   #        #   #     #
#     #  ######   #        #     #  #####    #####    #  ####  #######   #         #  ###     #        #  #  #  #  #  #  #     #  ######   #     #  ######    #####      #     #     #  #     #  #  #  #     #        #        #        #     #    #     #####    #####   #    #   ######   ######      #      #####    ######            #      ###     # #     #####      #             ###        ###   #         #           #####  #####         ##        ##  #    #
#######  #     #  #        #     #  #        #        #     #  #     #   #   #     #  #  #    #        #     #  #   # #  #     #  #        #   # #  #   #          #     #     #     #   #   #   #  #  #    # #       #       #         #     #    #    #              #  #######        #  #     #    #      #     #        #                   #     #######     #  #    # ###         #   # #     #     #         #             #           #####   #        #   #   #      ###  ###
#     #  #     #  #     #  #     #  #        #        #     #  #     #   #   #     #  #   #   #        #     #  #    ##  #     #  #        #    #   #    #   #     #     #     #     #    # #    #  #  #   #   #      #      #           #   #     #    #        #     #       #   #     #  #     #    #      #     #  #     #           ###             # #    #  #  #   #  # #         #    #             #       #              #                   #        #   #  #       ###  ###
#     #  ######    #####   ######   #######  #         #####   #     #  ###   #####   #    #  #######  #     #  #     #  #######  #         #### #  #     #   #####      #      #####      #      ## ##   #     #     #     #######       ###    #####  #######   #####        #    #####    #####     #       #####    #####            ###     #       # #     #####   #   ###          ###  #     #       ##   ##                                    ###  ###    # #         #   ###
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        #######                                     #          #
```

*NOTE:  Prints a question mark ('?') if no matching character*

ASCII Art courtesy of:  https://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&h=0&f=Banner

Comment: @Jetchisel - Thanks for the clarification.  I updated to explicitly declare '#!/bin/bash' as I missed this from the original answer.